# facing an issue with a4j:ajax on Ie9

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

In form there is a drop down and submit button.

```
<h:commandButton id="btnId" value="Submit>
    <a4j:ajax listener="mybean.method" execute="@form" render ='homeFormId'/>
 </h:commandButton>
```

when I click on button 'homeForm' is rendering:

1) In this homeForm I have "ui:include" tag which loads differnt xhtml/forms based on certain condition.

2) After this "ui:incude" tag other tags/content like panelgroup, textfeilds etc. are present in the form

So problem here is the included xhtml/form is loading completely. But the other content/tags are not loading in the parent form, which means any content after the include tag is not loading.

And this problem is only in IE and can't see this issue with chrome or mozilla

Note: If I use "h:commandButton type ="Submit" it is working in IE also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not related to your problem but `listener="mybean.method"` should be `listener="#{mybean.method}"`

Comment: I used correctly in app. It is typo mistake here

Comment: Do you have nested HTML forms? You can check it in IE Development Tools.